# How to get orders to buy at lows and sell at highs but code's wrong

Tags: mql4, algorithmic-trading, trading

Trying to get highs of current bar and sending an order when the bid gets there and same for the lows, but this code isn't working and I don't know what's wrong with it.

```
Void OnStart() 

{
   double i = High[0];
   double l = Low[0];
   
   int a = OrderSend(NULL,OP_SELL,0.04,Bid,5,100,200,NULL,clrNONE);
   int b = OrderSend(NULL,OP_BUY,0.04,Ask,5,100,200,NULL,clrNONE);
   if(i==Bid)
   {
   a
   }   
   else(l==Ask)
   {
   b
   }
```

Comment: How would you know the current day high and low before the trading day ends?

Comment: Pre determand variables High[0] an Low[0]